# open prettyphoto(multiple images) on a button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am using prettyphoto, in that i can able to open single image as a prettyphoto on a button click. But I need the mutiple images to be open as prettyphoto on a button click.

here is the code i'm used. In this `$image_src_cb1` is an array.

```
<?php $html .= $button_class_wrapper_open . "<a class='" . $button_class . $button_animation_class . $prettyphoto_class . "' data-rel='" . $pretty_photo_rel . "' href='" . $image_src_cb1 . "' ><span class='cover_boxes_button_text text_wrap'> " . $link_label1 .'</span>'. $button_icon . "<span class='a_overlay'></span></a>" . $button_class_wrapper_close;
```

can anyone give me suggestion to open multiple images on button click.

Comment: Did you mean you need to open image gallery where you can navigate between the images? like a slider?

Comment: @AbhijeetWebDev yes exacctly

Comment: In that case official website has the demo: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto

Comment: @AbhijeetWebDev the link you send is not having the (multiple images) open on a `button` click

Comment: do you mean with multiple images that you can switch with arrows between them or do you mean that they open all together on your screen like a grid

Comment: @EPKgames 
multiple images that you can switch with arrows between them

Answer (score 2):

Using version: 3.1.5

Add an identifier to each image. For example the `rel` attribute:

```
<img src="image--1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[myGallery]" alt="">
<img src="image--2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[myGallery]" alt="">
<img src="image--3.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[myGallery]" alt="">

<button type="button" class="foo">Gallery</button>
```

Pass the src attributes to prettyPhoto as an array:

```
$('.foo').on('click', function() {
    var ImgArr = [];

    $('[rel="prettyPhoto[myGallery]"]').each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        ImgArr.push(src);
    });
    $.prettyPhoto.open(ImgArr);
});
```